# Take a photo from multiple cameras at the same time

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, ionic-framework, capacitor

Using Capacitor (preferable) or Swift/Kotlin, how can I take a photo on both the front and rear cameras at the same time? I'm looking to replicate the same functionality as the social media app BeReal.

I tried the following but this prompts for the camera twice. I only want to prompt for the camera once and have it capture at both ends:

```
import { Camera, CameraDirection, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/camera';

const get_photo = async () => {
        const rear = await Camera.getPhoto({
            quality: 90,
            allowEditing: false,
            source: CameraSource.Camera,
            resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
            direction: CameraDirection.Rear
        });

        const front = await Camera.getPhoto({
            quality: 90,
            allowEditing: false,
            source: CameraSource.Camera,
            resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
            direction: CameraDirection.Front
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried BeReal (June 3rd 2023) on an iPhone. It does not take the picture of the back and front at the same time. But one (back) after the other (front) - i.e the user need to click the take picture button twice. As far as Im aware it is not possible to activate both cameras at the same time on iOS.

Comment: That will work fine for my use case. It gives the perception that it is only taking one photo -- that's what matters. I want to replicate the functionality where the user sees a single camera preview. When they click the "Capture image" button, two photos are taken at the same time (front and back).

Comment: I edited my post. On iOS BeReal prompts twice. i.e asks the user to take two pictures. You cannot take a photo without a user prompt on iOs

Comment: You can use https://github.com/capacitor-community/camera-preview plugin to show camera inside your html. show a button on camera and click to capture 1 (front) then switch programatically to 2(back) and capture image. you will have 2 images on 1 click. 2nd image and process will be programatically.